# Please, explain the use of 'would' in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning, modal-verbs, will-would

Please, explain the use of 'would' in this sentence

> I'm only 36, but I feel like I'm too old to understand and explain certain expressions sometimes.. (since this is something younger people **would** usually say)

Answer (score 1):

That use of "would" appears in this definition:

[American Heritage Dictionary "would"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=would)
"6. Used to express presumption or expectation"

The speaker believes that some expressions are most likely to be said by younger speakers. (They take that as a reason for not bothering to understand or explain the expressions.)

Let me suggest a corrected version of your sentence:
"I'm only 36, but I feel like I'm too old to understand and explain certain expressions, since they are things younger people would usually say."

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the word "would" suggests a presumption of an event occurring based on common knowledge. In fact, I would go further and say that its more of an assumption.

Here, the speaker is assuming that he is, for the lack of a better phrase, from an older generation, which used different phrases and expressions and as a result, might not be able to understand every colloquial slang used by the people he's referring to; unlike the more common usage "used to".